# node - how to use source-map with nyc and mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, istanbul, nyc

So nyc is mangling my files as follows:

```
  at _onCreate (src/post/admin.js:1:10453)
  at doQuery (src/db.js:59:216)
  at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

I am unsure of how to use a source map to unmangle this. The docs state:

**Accurate stack traces using source-maps.**

**When produce-source-map is set to true, then the instrumented source files will include inline source maps for the instrumenter transform. When combined with source-map-support, stack traces for instrumented code will reflect their original lines.**

So I tried the following npm run command:

```
"NODE_ENV=test nyc mocha --require ./tests/setup.js --require source-map-support/register --produce-source-map true --bail ./tests/unit/$FILE"
```

combined with the nyc setting:

```
"nyc": {
    "include": [
        "src"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "./tmp/**/*",
        "./tests"
    ],
    "instrument": true,
    "report-dir": "./tests/coverage",
    "temp-dir": "./tests/temp",
    "source-map": true,
    "produce-source-map": true
}
```

but the line is still mangled.

Answer (score 13):

the basic pre-condition for it to work would be (as described [here](https://istanbul.js.org/docs/tutorials/)):

```
npm install --save-dev source-map-support
```

make sure `nyc` is `^10.3.2` (`10.3.0` was broken).

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "mocha": "^3.3.0",
    "nyc": "^10.3.2",
    "source-map-support": "^0.4.15",
}
```

the `nyc` config should be `"sourceMap": true, "produce-source-map": true`.

and the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-support) explains how to use them:

**CLI Usage**

```
node -r source-map-support/register compiled.js
```

**Programmatic Usage**

Put the following line at the top of the compiled file.

```
require('source-map-support').install();
```

one can also define mapping file-names by adding comments:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=filename.js.map
```

Comment: Well I'm trying to use in their example of `$ mocha --require source-map-support/register tests/`, except that's pretty pointless since I can get the right line error without it in the first place. I'm just trying to work out how to incorporate it with nyc.

Comment: @A.Lau when `produce-source-map` is set to `true`, then the instrumented source files will include inline source maps... where the word "inline" tells where to find them. `sourceMappingURL` can be used not to inline. the issue tracker has quite some entries: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aopen+source-map

Comment: found another `nyc` config, which uses `sourceMap` instead of `source-map`.